# How to mutate dataframe inside do with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, lazyeval

Inside the `do` I am calling a `mutate_` with reference to the original dataframe.  The problem is that I can't get access to that dataframe inside the `mutate`.  This has to do with `lazyeval` package, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Thank you for your help.

For example, say this function returns a data_frame of points.

```
lattice_points <- function (x0, y0, r){
    df <- expand.grid(
            x1 = ceiling(x0-r):floor(x0+r),
            y1 = ceiling(y0-r):floor(y0+r)) %>% 
        filter((x1-x0)^2 + (y1-y0)^2 <= r^2)
    return (df)
}
```

Then I made another function to serialize this one (and I want to identify it with `id`):

```
many_lattice_points <- function (df, 
        id_ = "id", x_ = "x0", y_ = "y0", r_ = "r") {
    df_out <- rowwise(df_in) %>% 
        do( lattice_points(.[x_], .[y_], .[r_])) %>%
              mutate_(.dots = interp(~ .[var_], var_ = as.name(id_)))
    return (df_out)
}
```

With this input:

```
> input_df <- data_frame(
    id = c("a", "b"), x0 = c(0.5, 5.5), 
    y0 = c(0.5, 0.5), r  = c(1  , 1  ) )

    id     x0    y0    r
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a   0.5   0.5     1
2     b   5.5   0.5     1
```

I should get the following:

```
    id     x1    y1 
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> 
1     a   0.0   0.0 
2     a   0.0   1.0 
3     a   1.0   0.0 
4     a   1.0   1.0 
5     b   5.0   0.0 
6     b   5.0   1.0 
7     b   6.0   0.0 
8     b   6.0   1.0
```

However, I'm getting an error because it can't find the column `var_`.

Clarification: 
I have found other ways to go around it, but I would like to exploit the power of `do` with `lazyeval`.

Comment: I think you can do `do( data.frame(.[id_], lattice_points(.[[x_]], .[[y_]])) )`, but it's hard to tell without the `lattice_points` function.

Comment: Got it.  The problem is not in the double brackets, but in recognizing `.` as the dataframe before the function `lattice_points` inside of `do`.

Comment: I meant that I got the function `lattice_points`, not that I got the problem... by the way.

Comment: Did you try the code? My point was that you can likely get what you want within do and don't need mutate at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why using an `lapply` isn't an option?  This seems a lot easier: `lapply(seq(1, nrow(input_df), by = 1),
       function(i) {
         cbind(id = input_df[[i, 1]], lattice_points(input_df[[i, 2]], input_df[[i, 3]], input_df[[i, 4]]))
       }) %>%
dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
tbl_df()
`

Comment: Thank you @aosmith and @Peter.   I have indeed found ways to go around it, yet this one seems the most logical to me; and I haven't fully understood `lazyeval`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add an `id` column with `do` is to include it in the `group_by` before it.

```
many_lattice_points <- function (df, 
        id_ = "id", x_ = "x0", y_ = "y0", r_ = "r") {
    df_check <- count_(id_)
    if (not(all(data_check$n == 1))) 
        warning("The function may not work as expected")

    df_out <- group_by_(df_in, .dots = id_) %>% 
        do( lattice_points(.[x_], .[y_], .[r_]) ) 
    return (df_out)
}
```

While there's still an issue with how to do it with `lazyeval`, this is satisfactory in terms of purpose and logically.